# MySQL Trigger IF Statement Error (Won't Create)

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to create Trigger like this, if student have score above like this
 the score on other column will automatic inserting value (alphabetic)

```
 DELIMITER |
    CREATE TRIGGER N_Angka BEFORE INSERT ON nilai
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF nilai_angka <= 50 THEN
                UPDATE nilai SET NEW.nilai_huruf = 'C-';
            ELSE IF nilai_angka < 55 THEN
                UPDATE nilai SET NEW.nilai_huruf = 'C';
            ELSE IF nilai_angka < 59 THEN
                UPDATE nilai SET NEW.nilai_huruf = 'C+';
            ELSE IF nilai_angka <= 60 THEN
                UPDATE nilai SET NEW.nilai_huruf = 'B-';
            ELSE IF nilai_angka < 75 THEN
                UPDATE nilai SET NEW.nilai_huruf = 'B';
            ELSE IF nilai_angka <= 80 THEN
                UPDATE nilai SET NEW.nilai_huruf = 'B+';
            ELSE IF nilai_angka <= 85 THEN
                UPDATE nilai SET NEW.nilai_huruf = 'A-';
            ELSE IF nilai_angka <= 90 THEN
                UPDATE nilai SET NEW.nilai_huruf = 'A';
            ELSE IF nilai_angka <= 99 THEN
                UPDATE nilai SET NEW.nilai_huruf = 'A+';
            ELSE
                UPDATE nilai SET NEW.nilai_huruf = 'S';
            END IF;
    END |
    DELIMITER ;
```

it says there is error in line 26 it's on the

```
END IF;
```

can someone explain and provide some solution for me

Comment: i don't know it's say the eror in line 26
END IF;
please help me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `UPDATE` but you can set the value of `NEW.nilai_huruf`based on `NEW.nilai_angka` because it's a `BEFORE` trigger.

Use `CASE` expression to make more succinct.

Since it's now a one statement trigger you no longer need to use `BEGIN...END` block.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER N_Angka
BEFORE INSERT ON nilai
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.nilai_huruf = CASE 
    WHEN NEW.nilai_angka <=50              THEN 'C-'
    WHEN NEW.nilai_angka BETWEEN 51 AND 54 THEN 'C'
    WHEN NEW.nilai_angka BETWEEN 55 AND 58 THEN 'C+'
    WHEN NEW.nilai_angka BETWEEN 59 AND 60 THEN 'B-'
    WHEN NEW.nilai_angka BETWEEN 61 AND 74 THEN 'B'
    WHEN NEW.nilai_angka BETWEEN 75 AND 80 THEN 'B+'
    WHEN NEW.nilai_angka BETWEEN 81 AND 85 THEN 'A-'
    WHEN NEW.nilai_angka BETWEEN 86 AND 90 THEN 'A'
    WHEN NEW.nilai_angka BETWEEN 91 AND 99 THEN 'A+'
    ELSE 'S' END;
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7594f7/1)** demo

---

You most likely want to create a complimentary `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger.
At this point it makes sense to extract the logic into a function

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION angka_huruf(_angka INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(2) DETERMINISTIC
RETURN CASE 
  WHEN _angka <=50              THEN 'C-'
  WHEN _angka BETWEEN 51 AND 54 THEN 'C'
  WHEN _angka BETWEEN 55 AND 58 THEN 'C+'
  WHEN _angka BETWEEN 59 AND 60 THEN 'B-'
  WHEN _angka BETWEEN 61 AND 74 THEN 'B'
  WHEN _angka BETWEEN 75 AND 80 THEN 'B+'
  WHEN _angka BETWEEN 81 AND 85 THEN 'A-'
  WHEN _angka BETWEEN 86 AND 90 THEN 'A'
  WHEN _angka BETWEEN 91 AND 99 THEN 'A+'
  ELSE 'S' END;
```

And then reuse it in both triggers

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER N_Angka
BEFORE INSERT ON nilai
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.nilai_huruf = angka_huruf(NEW.nilai_angka);

CREATE TRIGGER N_Angka2
BEFORE UPDATE ON nilai
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.nilai_huruf = angka_huruf(NEW.nilai_angka);
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/062a4/1)** demo

---

Now, alternatively you can ditch triggers and `nilai_huruf` column altogether and just use the function whenever you fetch your records

```sql
SELECT nilai_angka, angka_huruf(nilai_angka) nilai_huruf
  FROM nilai;
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a4131/1)** demo

Comment: Thanks peterm for the answer but i've already solved this problem
i change event on the trigger to AFTER

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER N_Angka BEFORE INSERT ON nilai
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.nilai_angka <= 50 THEN
            BEGIN
                SET NEW.nilai_huruf = 'C-';
                END;
        ELSEIF NEW.nilai_angka < 55 THEN
            BEGIN
                SET NEW.nilai_huruf = 'C';
                END;
        ELSEIF NEW.nilai_angka < 59 THEN
            BEGIN
                SET NEW.nilai_huruf = 'C+';
                END;
        ELSEIF NEW.nilai_angka <= 60 THEN
            BEGIN
                SET NEW.nilai_huruf = '-B';
                END;
        ELSEIF NEW.nilai_angka < 75 THEN
            BEGIN
                SET NEW.nilai_huruf = 'B';
                END;
        ELSEIF NEW.nilai_angka <= 80 THEN
            BEGIN
            SET NEW.nilai_huruf = 'B+';
                END;
        ELSEIF NEW.nilai_angka <= 85 THEN
            BEGIN
            SET NEW.nilai_huruf = 'A-';
                END;
        ELSEIF NEW.nilai_angka <= 90 THEN
            BEGIN
            SET NEW.nilai_huruf = 'A';
                END;
        ELSEIF NEW.nilai_angka <= 99 THEN
            BEGIN
            SET NEW.nilai_huruf = 'A+';
                END;
        ELSEIF NEW.nilai_angka = 100 THEN
            BEGIN
            SET NEW.nilai_huruf = 'S';
                END; 
                END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

This is the Answer
i change the event on the trigger